# Selecting a column such as a player only once first by a max value then by a min value

Tags: sql

So I've two tables 'AllBowlRecords' and one 'AggregateBowlRecords'

AllBowlRecords :-

```
plr_fullnm|Wkts|Runs
---------------------
Bumrah    |  4 | 23
Bumrah    |  2 | 7
Bumrah    |  1 | 51
Bumrah    |  4 | 39
Jason     |  3 | 48
Jason     |  3 | 29
Jason     |  3 | 70
```

So all I want is to update AggregateBowlRecords based on AllBowlRecords where Wkts is MAX, but if there's multiple occurrences of MAX Wkts value, then whichever corresponds minimum runs should be selected. And AggregateBowlRecords should look like this:

```
Bumrah    |  4 | 23
Jason     |  3 | 29
```

What are the possible solutions?

Comment: Most DBMSes support `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY plr_fullnm ORDER BY Wkts DESC, Runs ASC)`

Answer (score 0):

You can return the results you want using a query with `row_number()`:

```
select plr_fullnm, Wkts, Runs
from (select abr.*,
             row_number() over (partition by plr_fullnm order by wkts desc, runs) as seqnum
      from AllBowlRecords abr
     ) abr
where seqnum = 1;
```